# Extract HTML content from XML in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltype

I am migrating an application from Sedna to Oracle. I have a collection/table that contents HTML code.

```
<descriptions>
  <description acad-plan="SAGSY1">
    <p>
      <strong>test?</strong>
    </p>
    <p>test</p>
  </description>
</descriptions>
```

My goal is to extract the HTML content of `<description>` tag. When I run the following query, it returns the content but it removes the HTML tags.

```
SELECT xmllines.* FROM
XMLTABLE ( '/descriptions'
    PASSING xmltype('<descriptions> 
<description acad-plan="SAGSY1">
<p>
  <strong>test?</strong>
</p>
<p>test</p>
</description>
</descriptions>'
) COLUMNS
        id VARCHAR2(512) PATH 'description'
) xmllines;
```

The output of this query is :

```
test?test
```

What I am looking for is

```
<p><strong>test </strong> </p> <p>test</p>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: When you write which query? Also please include the the original value, the result you get now, and what you want to end up with.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I want to extract the content of <description> tag as is. The query I am using is: 

select * from 
xmltype(bfilename('PTOOL_TMP', 'program-details.xml'), nls_charset_id('UTF-8') )
columns html varchar2(1025)      path '/descriptions/description'

Thanks

Comment: Please **[edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49013353/edit)** to include your code and other information.

Comment: @AlexPoole I did. Do I need to specify more? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You appear to want one of these:

```
select html
from xmltable('/'
  passing xmltype('<descriptions>
  <description acad-plan="SAGSY1">
    <p>
      <strong>test?</strong>
    </p>
    <p>test</p>
  </description>
</descriptions>')
  columns html xmltype path '/descriptions/description/*');

select html
from xmltable('/descriptions'
  passing xmltype('<descriptions>
  <description acad-plan="SAGSY1">
    <p>
      <strong>test?</strong>
    </p>
    <p>test</p>
  </description>
</descriptions>')
  columns html xmltype path 'description/*'
);

select html
from xmltable('/descriptions/description'
  passing xmltype('<descriptions>
  <description acad-plan="SAGSY1">
    <p>
      <strong>test?</strong>
    </p>
    <p>test</p>
  </description>
</descriptions>')
  columns html xmltype path '*'
);
```

depending on the number and type of repeated nodes; if any; or if there is only one node to extract you coudl use an XMLQuery instead:

```
select xmlquery('/descriptions/description/*'
  passing xmltype('<descriptions>
  <description acad-plan="SAGSY1">
    <p>
      <strong>test?</strong>
    </p>
    <p>test</p>
  </description>
</descriptions>')
  returning content) as html
from dual;
```

All of those get the same output:

```
HTML                                                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<p><strong>test?</strong></p><p>test</p>
```

I've changed the path to get `*` under the description node; and changed the returned column type from the XMLTable calls to XMLType. The XMLQuery returns that type too.

If you want the result as a plain string you can use the XMLType `getStringVal()` function; like this for the XMLTable versions:

```
select xmltype.getStringVal(html) as html
from xmltable(...)
```

or like this for the XMLQuery version:

```
select xmlquery('/descriptions/description/*'
  passing xmltype('<descriptions>
  <description acad-plan="SAGSY1">
    <p>
      <strong>test?</strong>
    </p>
    <p>test</p>
  </description>
</descriptions>')
  returning content).getStringVal() as html
from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for the response. It works perfectly. And thanks for your patience. Have a good day!